# IntPtr.ToInt32() and x64 systems

Tags: windows-8, 64-bit, intptr, overflowexception

In my c# dll I have some code like this to interact with some unmanaged dlls:

```
IntPtr buffer = ...;
TTPOLYGONHEADER header = (TTPOLYGONHEADER)Marshal.PtrToStructure(
                       new IntPtr(buffer.ToInt32() + index), typeof(TTPOLYGONHEADER));
```

This has always worked fine when using my dll compiled in AnyCPU with .Net2 and .Net4 on x64 systems, before installing Windows 8.

With Windows 8 when using the .Net4 dll I get an OverFlowException ("Arithmetic operation resulted in an overflow.") at the buffer.ToInt32() call.

The MSDN documentation for IntPtr.ToInt32() says this:

"OverflowException: On a 64-bit platform, the value of this instance is too large or too small to represent as a 32-bit signed integer."

I wonder why this problem has surfaced only with Windows 8, and what is the correct way to fix it.

Should I use a method like this, instead of the IntPtr.ToInt32() call?

```
    internal static long GetPtr(IntPtr ptr)
    {
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4) // x86

            return ptr.ToInt32();

        return ptr.ToInt64(); // x64
    }
```

Comment: *Always* use ToInt64().  Or cast to (long).

Comment: Hans Passant, please post it as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be calling any of the conversion functions just to add and offset and immediately convert back.  `IntPtr` has *two* built-in ways to directly add an offset, either of

[`IntPtr.Add(buffer, index)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.add.aspx)

or simply

[`(buffer + index)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.intptr.op_addition.aspx)